# Why does require() give me a new copy of a module when loaded from a different location?

Tags: node.js, coffeescript, hubot

I'm pretty new to Node.JS development and I'm trying to create a Hubot adapter.

The `hubot` module exports a class named `TextMessage` I need to use. In my adapter, I create an instance of this and pass it to the running robot like so:

```
{Adapter, TextMessage} = require 'hubot'
class MyAdapter extends Adapter
  onNewMessage: (text) =>
    @receive new TextMessage text
```

However, [in Hubot's own code it is checking that my message is an `instanceof TextMessage`](https://github.com/github/hubot/blob/379538cd3003d832b65d741d756ae10460b842af/src/listener.coffee#L42). When I run a bot and use my adapter, this check always fails.

The project structure is laid out like this:

```
my-bot
 |- node_modules
    |- my-adapter
    |  |- node_modules
    |  |  |- hubot
    |- hubot
```

As a result `require('hubot')` in `my-adapter` is giving me a **different** copy of the `hubot` module as the one given to `my-bot`.

I'm pretty sure I'm not understanding some fundamental concept of Node modules here. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason it is designed this way is so that it's possible for a module to always get a "fresh" version (that has not been modified by any libraries such as your one).  Generally, if you `require()` one of your dependencies, then you should be able to rely on default behaviour for that module.  *(The alternative is unpredictable and possibly insecure.)*

If the purpose of your module is to *adapt* another module, then you should either:

### Return a modified module

For example, your module might do:

```
module.exports = require('hubot');
// ... your custom modifications
```

Or:

```
var hubot = module.exports.hubot = require('hubot');
```

This means that the app itself wouldn't depend on `hubot`, but only your module.

### Not list `hubot` as a dependency for your adapter

Node.js `require()` calls cascade up the path - so if you simply don't install `hubot` as a dependency, then you can still `require()` it, and it will use the version from the app.

This means that it's possible to install your module without installing `hubot`, thus causing problems - but on the other hand, it also allows *multiple* modules to modify the same base module.

Personally, I'd opt for the second option.

Comment: Ah, I didn't realize that `require()` calls would cascade up the directory path. Since there's no real reason to use my module outside the context of an existing hubot instance, I'll just remove `hubot` as a dependency from my module.

Comment: I would highly suggest avoiding the second option.  This would cause your module to be _very_ environment dependent (it would crash if `hubot` wasn't installed somewhere above it).  The first option is the way node modules are expected to be designed.

Comment: I've seen the second pattern used for some quite popular modules that are designed to be extended like this.  For example, the [`passport-oauth`](https://www.npmjs.org/package/passport-oauth) module adds OAuth support to `passport`, but it doesn't have `passport` as a dependency.  That way, you can enhance Passport with a bunch of different functionality from different modules, which is not possible with the first option.